# Can't convert POST body as buffer to string in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I send the following body of POST request to my server app on Node.js

```
...
body: JSON.stringify({
    content: 'Text'
})
...
```

On Node.js I try to receive the request body and convert it from buffer to string:

```
let chunks = [];
req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
});
req.on('end', function() {
    res.writeHead(200);
    let data = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    let jsonStr = data.toString('utf8');
    res.end(JSON.parse(jsonStr).content);
});
```

But I receive the error

> Unexpected end of JSON

I'm interested in a solution without Express - just Node.js build-in http server

Comment: Print the string to the console, then run it through a JSON validator - is the response valid? or cut off?

Comment: @casraf if `res.end(data.toString())` then I receive `{"content":"Text"}`

Comment: Is the error in server or client

Comment: @JaromandaX I run Node.js on Windows via CMD, so I see the error in the CMD after the command `node app.js`